# Getting ng-class to work for dynamically created elements

Tags: angularjs, dynamically-generated, ng-class

I am making an application that dynamically creates a bunch of labels. Each one needs an ng-class parameter but Angular doesn't see the newly created elements and so it is ignored.
http://jsfiddle.net/vdkuqhg7/

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#box' ) );
var div = angular.element('<div ng-class=\"{\'red\' : areaStatus, \'green\' : !areaStatus}\">This is more text</div>');
myEl.append(div);
```

How do I get it to recognize the newly created elements?

Comment: you should really avoid using `angular.element` whenever possible, it's almost like using jquery.   When you have no other choice but to use `angular.element`, it's best to use it inside a directive where you can recompile the scope.  however, what you are trying to do can be easily done using `ng-repeat`.  I say every day in a post here, it's always better to code against your data than code against the DOM.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite your fiddle with an ng-repeat, just as an exercise in showing how you can avoid operating on an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would perform the task you have presented; it utilizes some angular features differently. I understand that it doesn't use `angular.element` as your question does, but it is generally more flexible. Here is the relevant code:

```
myModule.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.areaStatus = false;

    $scope.dynamicData = [];

$scope.insertDiv=function(message) {
    if (message)
    {
        $scope.dynamicData.push({value : message})
    }
    else{
    $scope.dynamicData.push({value: "This is more text"});
    }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" id="box">
        <button ng-click="areaStatus = !areaStatus">Toggle</button>
        <div ng-class="{'red' : areaStatus, 'green' : !areaStatus}">
            This is some text
        </div>

<button ng-click="insertDiv()">insert</button>
<button ng-click="insertDiv('This is a different Message')">insert different message</button>

<div ng-repeat="data in dynamicData" ng-class="{'red' : areaStatus, 'green' : !areaStatus}">
    {{data.value}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkv4y340/

Comment: I like it. @Claies, How would I go about specifying an absolute location in that ng-repeat. Each label would have a different location. I currently do this with jQuery and append the element with inline parameters.

Comment: The easiest would be to have a variable per label instead of ng-repeat, or even extend the object the label aids with a new property.  You could even write a directive that references a specific element in the array per location

Comment: The end goal here is to model the app in data, then render the data, instead of trying to model the DOM

Comment: I don't know what you mean by variable per label. Can I have dynamic parameters in the div tag like "top:{{label.top}}"

Comment: Sure, just make label an object instead of an array, an add properties named for each section (i.e. label.top, label.right, label.home, etc.) sorry for formatting, posting from phone

Comment: the best way to look at angular is that it is the dynamic manager.  anything that you think should be dynamic should be stored in a variable on scope, for use in expressions `{{ }}`.  In anglar, your "data" is more than just the values of the form fields, it is essentially any variable that would change or be interacted with on screen, much like a desktop app.

Comment: This is right but i got trouble with datepicker class in dynamic html. How can i solve it

Answer (score 2):

See [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile). You can use this service similarly to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/haydenk/vdkuqhg7/1/

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myController', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.areaStatus = false;


$scope.insertDiv=function() {
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#box' ) );
    var div = angular.element('<div ng-class=\"{\'red\' : areaStatus, \'green\' : !areaStatus}\">This is more text</div>');
        myEl.append(div);
        $compile(div)($scope);
}
```

Comment: You should not write any HTML into the controller. Bad code

Comment: I like this answer because it gives me the functionality that I was looking for ($compile). I may need this snippet some where else as I try to shed my jquery ways :)

Comment: @Shohel I agree. I am sure there is a better way to do this but I do not have enough information to know exactly what he is trying to accomplish.